# Can Windows Phone Apps see the User/Device ID?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm building a Windows Phone App that involves users talking to each other through a web service.  Does Windows Phone expose the User or Device ID to the app that I can use to identify the different users?  Better yet would be a federated login through Live ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a Device ID that you can use that is unique to each phone. You get it via the Device Information which you can read about here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

And then you can read about it a little more on this blog post with a more full featured example.

http://www.nickharris.net/2010/09/windows-phone-7-how-to-find-the-device-unique-id-windows-live-anonymous-id-and-manufacturer/